# Keyboard shortcut to duplicate tab in pantheon-terminal?

Tags: terminal, keyboard-shortcuts, elementary-os, terminal-emulator

I often open several tabs in my terminal ([`pantheon-terminal`](https://launchpad.net/pantheon-terminal)). I can use <kbd>Ctrl+Shift+T</kbd> to open a new tab.

I was wondering if there is a similar key combination to **duplicate** the present tab (i.e. have it in the same location)?

I can right-click on any tab and choose "Duplicate", but I don't know how to do it via the keyboard.

This is what I am trying to reproduce with keys:

[image: Duplicate command]

I'm running Elementary OS.

Comment: `bash` has no notion of "tabs". You may be talking about some terminal emulator? Which one?

Comment: Yes, please [edit] your question and tell us what terminal emulator you are using. Bash is the shell, it isn't the same as the terminal window you see, the terminal window is just running bash. So you need to check (probably) Help=>About or something similar and tell us what terminal emulator you use.

Comment: @Kusalananda thanks for your comments! I have added the terminal emulator, which is *pantheon-terminal* if I am not mistaken. Your comments already helped me by pointing out that this is not a shell-thing